# Difference between content_main.xml and activity_main.xml?

Tags: android, xml

I am new to Android App development. I have Android Studio 1.4. In my layout folder I have two XML files (`content_main.xml` and `activity_main.xml`). I have been following Bucky's tutorial and he just has the `activity_main.xml`. Which one should I use?

Comment: can you post the link to the tutorial?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9l1lfWAiHPg

Comment: You should be using `activity_main.xml`. check my answer

Comment: content_main.xml is used for the fab and activity_main.xml is for other part of the activity.

Answer (score 73):

Unlike previous version, the new API 23 comes with the `coordinatorLayout` and stuff and just to make them simple to use android has distinguished activity's layout into two different layout i.e. `content_main.xml` & `activity_main.xml`.

I'll explain what they are for:

1. `activity_main.xml`

this xml file is used to display `coordinatorLayout`, `tabLayout`, `floatingActionButton`, `viewPager` etc..

2. `content_main.xml`

This xml file is use to display your stuff i.e. what you want to display to users.

So, if you are just asking in which xml you have to put your stuff, `content_main.xml` is the one....

Comment: Just to elaborate - and see @SherlockSun's answer - he's the only one who explicitly points out that activity_main.xml contains an "include" for content_mail.xml. These two layout files are related, they describe different aspects of the overall layout.

Comment: That's right...But for those who are new to the android environment explaining things this way is much better...and the question was about which XML to use.

Comment: @Chordin4tion - What if I dont want to use coordinatorLayout, tabLayout, floatingActionButton or viewPager and want a simple layout? Do I still use content_main.xml and leave activity_main.xml unused?

Comment: @Shubs That's totally up to you...If you don't want to use two different layout you can use `activity_main.xml` and remove the include tag from `activity_main.xml`. You can remove coordinator layout, tab layout and other stuff and replace parent layout with whatever layout you are planning to use.

Comment: "stuff i.e. what you want to display to users" –Floating action button is not something you want to display to users?

Answer (score 15):

I think the `content_main.xml` is a part of `activity_main.xml`.
Because there is `include layout="@layout/content_main"` in the `activity_main.xml`.

Answer (score 6):

Android Studio 1.4 gives a default new option of `content_main.xml` in the activity. actually activity load the xml file of `activity_main.xml` for your layout. `content_main.xml` is the part of `main.xml`.
you can use both for layout,but `main.xml` is necessary for your Activity. its a option to choose the `content_main.xml` for design of layout.
Hope you get it.

Answer (score 2):

The `activity_main.xml` is the "outer" part of the activity layout (toolbar, action button, etc.) and `content_main.xml` is the inner part where you put your own layout (the blank space).

`content_main.xml` file will be generated when you choose "blank activity". This activity will be having floating button by default at the bottom of the screen.

But when you choose "empty activity" then `content_main.xml` won't be generated and it won't be having floating button, but just simple Activity.

Answer (score 2):

activity_main and content_main are linked to each other.

You can use either both. But to be specific, you should use activity_main.

let me explain this further.

**activity_main**, this is where the content_main is placed. This is a mother and child case, where activity_main is the mother and content_main is the child.

**content_main**, this is where you put your controls / content e.g button. This represents as the body of your design.

Answer (score -2):

These are just 2 xml layout files which basically represent 2 different layouts. You should use the file based on the layout you want to use in your android app.

Based on the tutorial it is simple that you should use `activity_main.xml` as it is the layout for the `MainActivity`.

You can also see the preview of the layout file in android studio as to how it will look in the app.

Comment: rellay? Are you sure?

Comment: use content_main.xml for adding all the elements

Comment: This is not correct - they are not two different layouts. See @SherlockSun's answer - he's the only one who explicitly points out that activity_main.xml contains an "include" for content_mail.xml. So the two layout files are related, they describe different aspects of the overall layout.

Comment: Let's put it in another way,  when you embed some html code to the html code, it does not  mean that those html's are different pages.  There is only one page but consisted of two pieces...