# Android User interface: activity_main.xml & content_main.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new in Android development. At the moment I am trying figure out how Android user interface is created.

I remember, previously, user interface & layout was designed in `activity_main.xml` files.

I have created a new activity, which generated me two files for user interface: `activity_main.xml` & `content_main.xml`. It seems, that `content_main.xml` contains layout and user interface elements. In this case, what `activity_main.xml`. Do I have to use it?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Open your new created activity class, search for "setContentView". The layout used here is most likely used for your layout.
You should post your activitys source code to get a more specific answer.

Comment: File `MainActivity.java` has link to `activity_main.xml` which has also link to `content_main.xml`. I just can't understand it...

Comment: can you post your code in your MainActivity

Comment: may be the possibility your activity_main.xml includes content_main.xml to render ui . check this in activity_main.xml

Comment: ok, post your MainActivity.java, your activity_main.xml and your content_main.xml

Comment: it is just default best practice to separate layout and main content xmls, you can actually delete content_main.xml and use the old approach, be sure to delete the reference from activity_main.xml too

Comment: Hi welcome to android development, please check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6812066/4503373

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/32880945/363262 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183107/difference-between-content-main-xml-and-activity-main-xml

Comment: So, as far as I understand, `activity_main.xml` should contain appearance of user interface elements, who are provided in `content_main.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

> you should use it . you use include layout to keep clean and understandable your xml..most of the time your xml is to big which is very difficult to find any view(Button,Image etc) ..rather than including entire view into one xml we seprate them and include them ....when you setContentView your layout only one view hierarchy is created..

Comment: So, lets get back to my question, what kind of things should be in `activity_main.xml` and what should be provided in `content_main.xml`. Is that correct?

Comment: one situation may be where you can put NavigationView in to your activity_main.xml and you fragments layout which change based on your selected navigation item should be in content_main.xml...it depends on you what you want to add

Comment: I want to create a simple screen without navigation bar with user interface elements inside.

Comment: you can put your user interface elements inside in content_main.xml or remove content.xml and put your user interface elements inside in activity_main.xml...you are free to what you want to do..android does not force you to include layout ..it is a feature of IDE which generate you a include layout tag

Comment: And what are the advantages of not removing it? If I want not to remove, what should I do with `activity_main.xml`? I suppose it is Google recommendation to use multiple files...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use activity_main.xml because it is the root layout. As per my knowledge content_main.xml is for fab. So if you want a new button or anything you can directly add it to activity_main.xml. Many people recommend to use multiple files because now if you want same layout as content_main.xml in another layout file you can directly include that. This is the advantage which multiple file usage provides.