# Why the layout is in content_main

Tags: android

I have watched a few tutorials about android and they always work in the activity_main where they have the layout and they add  buttons and other stuff, but on my android studio the layout is in the content_main and I add there all the buttons, is there any difference if I work on content_main instead of activity_main?? if so how do I setup android studio to put the Relative Layout page in activity_main?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183107/difference-between-content-main-xml-and-activity-main-xml

Comment: You can name it whatever you want, `content_main.xml`, `activity_main.xml`, `why_wont_this_work_main.xml` as long as that's the one you inflate in `setContentView()` in the Activity where you want to use that layout