# What has to be used, content_main or Activity_main?

Tags: android, android-studio

Since after the new update in Android studio, the addition of the XML files has brought some confusion.

While setting the parameters for `setContentView()`, which XML has to be used? Content_main or Activity_main ?

And if I want to add an Layout file (XML) do I have to create 2 files with the same names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While setting the parameters for setContentView, which XML has to be
>   typed ? Content_main or Activity_main ?

You should use `content_main.xml` to put your views but pass 
`activity_main.xml` as the parameter to you `setContentView()` method.

`activity_main.xml` is used to display coordinatorLayout, tabLayout, floatingActionButton, viewPager etc.

`content_main.xml` is used to display your stuff i.e. what you want to display to users.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183107/difference-between-content-main-xml-and-activity-main-xml)

> And if I want to add an Layout file (XML) do I have to create 2 files
>   with the same name ?

Totally depends on the nature of the activity you are creating the layout for. The difference above will help you decide whether you need two or one.