# What is the point of `Content_main.xml`?

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-layout, android-activity

### To my understanding, the `content` file is just the `xml` files contents...but in a separate file. Whats the point?

I've seen

[What is the role of content_main.xml in android studio 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880722/what-is-the-role-of-content-main-xml-in-android-studio-1-4)

and there doesn't seem to be much documentation about `content_XXX.xml`, so I was wondering, why did the new update include the default creation of this file?

Why divide the code into two files, why not just put all of the contents in its own xml file, I've tried it...and it works. I fail to understand why the `content_main` file is generated on creation of a new project.

**Can someone give me a list of benefits of why I should be using the `content` file?**

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: @MD What is the point of that though? Isn't creating two files worse than creating one?

Answer (score 2):

`activity_main.xml` is used to display coordinatorLayout, tabLayout, floatingActionButton, viewPager etc.

`content_main.xml` is used to display your stuff i.e. what you want to display to users.

for more details check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34685861/1957401).

*Update after conversation in comments below:* The point of doing this is to bring in more organization in the code. We can always go forward with the old way of putting everything in one file. Android Studio is just giving us a start with keeping the layouts in a more organized way to allow easy comprehension of code and reuse wherever possible, by segregating related stuff.

Comment: But what is the point of all of that? Can't  juts keep all of my stuff in `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: it is more organized. you could also just keep the entire app's content in one xml and show and hide stuff as you need them and reposition them. Technically it is possible, but do we do that? no, because it is not convenient and organized. Seperating things out into separate files as much as we can will bring in more organizing and allow reuse also to certain extent.

Comment: so android studio is just giving us a start with proper organizing. We can always remove one file and put everything in one way if we want.

Comment: Ok, I understand it is about organization...but why break up one screen into two xml files? I understand why we would create different screen xml files, but this doesn't make logical sense to me...

Comment: to allow reuse. You may want to inflate a different set of content in the same activity but changes in ` tabLayout, floatingActionButton, viewPager` are rare.